# Gtk vala css expected identifier

Tags: gtk3

Trying to link css to vala code but when I compile I get this error

`error: syntax error, expected identifier`

Any reason for why this is happening?

Css link code:

```
Gtk.CssProvider css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
css_provider.load_from_path ("style.css");
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen (Gdk.Screen.get_default (), css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

Comment: This _could_ be made suitable for [so], but you need a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, not a couple of isolated lines, to demonstrate the problem.  And you'll need to tag for the language being used, too.

Comment: Can  you update the question and include the `style.css` or a link to `style.css`?